# How to create an instance of one class object with the function of another class object in Python?

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap, elementtree, python-itertools

I'm trying to use the `iterparse` funciton of ElementTree to parse a large OpenStreetMap (OSM) XML file. I'm trying to define my OSM file and its elements as class objects to help with my later analysis.

Now I've successfully defined an `OSM` class:

- `parse()` uses a generator to iterparse the OSM file. It yields `elem` (elements in OpenStreetMap).
- `reset()` reset the generator to avoid exhaustion.
- `slice()` uses itertools to make views of the OSM file by passing the index of start, stop and step. It returns a list of `elem`.
- `iloc()` called the slice function to locate a specific `elem`.
- `getchild()` returns the secondary element of an element with a given index.

---

My problem is: **I want to make another class `elem` to create functions on a single element. However, I must only generate an instance of `elem` through calling a function of `OSM`. 
i.e. I have *class1*. And when I call a function of an instance of *class1*, it should create and return an instance of *class2*.**

How can I achive this?

Here is my current code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools


class OSM:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.parser = ET.iterparse(self.data, events=('start', ))

    def parse(self):
        _, root = next(self.parser)
        for event, elem in self.parser:
            yield elem
            elem.clear()
            root.clear()

    def reset(self):
        self.parser = ET.iterparse(self.data, events=('start', ))

    def slice(self, start=0, stop=1, step=1):
        self.reset()
        view = []
        for i in itertools.islice(self.parse(), start, stop, step):
            view.append(i)
        return view

    def iloc(self, index):
        self.reset()
        return self.slice(index, index + 1)[0]

    def getchild(self, index):
        self.reset()
        elem = self.iloc(index)
        childdict = defaultdict(list)
        for i, child in enumerate(list(elem)):
            childdict[i] = [child.tag, child.attrib]
        return dict(childdict)
```

Comment: You do it the same way you instantiate any other class at any other place in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way:

```
class Mother(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def reproduce(self):
        return Child()

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```